# Is it better to use hidden inputs or query string variables in a forms action attribute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Suppose my controller looks like this

```
public ActionResult DoSomething(int id)
{
    Customer c = GetCustomerByID(id);
    return View(c);
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoSomething(int id, FormCollection formData)
{
    Customer c = GetCustomerByID(id);
    //Do something here
    return View(c);
}
```

What is the best way to send the id when submitting the form. There are two options

```
<form method="post" action="@Url.Action("DoSomething", "Customer", new { id = Model.ID })">
</form>
```

Or

```
<form method="post" action="@Url.Action("DoSomething", "Customer")">
    <input type="hidden" value="@Model.ID" />
</form>
```

The value of id is passed in two different ways, but the Controller doesn't really care, as it will be turned into a method parameter regardless. I was wondering what the "best practice" is for doing this.

Note: I didn't use any helpers in this example on purpose. I find them to be more limitting, then "helpful".

Comment: If Id is your record limiter and you are taking action on the customer for that id, then does id already exist in your route (Customer/Id/Action)? If so, just pass it on the route, neither the qs nor the post.

Answer (score 3):

There is no *better* way. Both are perfectly fine. The first one sends the id as part of the query string allowing users to bookmark the resulting page and come back later (if you remove the `[HttpPost]` of course). The second one sends the id as part of the POST request body so it is not directly visible to the user.

Answer (score 1):

As Darin says, you can do either.  It's up to you.

However, since you're doing a POST, you probably only want to use querystring parameters for record selection, and use other form elements for the actual data posted.

If you're doing a GET (which should only be done if returning a record, or some other non-state changing action) then querystrings are your only option, and the browser will add any form elements to the querystring automatically (so it won't matter if explicitly make it a querystring or not).